# Authenticate from Authenticator Okhttp3 has 200 response code but it keeps calling til message Too many follow-up requests: 21

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using ADFS server...
In Authenticator (authenticate), constantly getting

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=XXX}

but at the end

> onFailure: Too many follow-up requests: 21.

Retrofit 2.3.0

Comment: did you fix this ? I am facing similar issue

Comment: Facing a similar issue in Google API Integration.. Any fixes?